# Stream live proprietary content via CDN

Tags: cdn, live-streaming, codec, mpeg-dash

Requirement: be able to stream live proprietary binary data at scale from a cloud environment.

Possible solution:
Using a CDN, is it possible to stream live non-video data in a protocol that is agnostic of the video codec (e.g. MPEG-DASH)?

Seems that both Azure and AWS CDNs support MPEG-DASH, and MPEG-DASH is agnostic of the video codec it contains.

Does this solution make sense? What would one have to implement? (would a proprietary mock video codec + interfacing with MPEG-DASH be sufficient?)

Comment: What are your latency requirements?  DASH is just HTTP-based.  Just chunks of data which are uploaded, and then downloaded.  Some CDNs support chunked transfer so that the upload/download can occur around the same time.  But, if you can handle a few seconds of latency (which is what you'll end up with via DASH/HLS anyway), there's no need to make this complicated.  Chunk your data up into pieces, upload them, and download them.

Comment: Yes, a few seconds of latency is reasonable. Your suggestion sounds great, but how would these chunks interface with a CDN? Will a CDN support caching of arbitrary binary data in HTTP for real time streaming?

Comment: Yes.  The CDN doesn't know or care that the chunks were just created in near-realtime.  It just knows there's a new file/resource that clients are requesting.  They'll be cached like anything else.

Comment: So the solution would be fully HTTP based, right? The client would ask for a URL, the server would serve that URL, and the result would be cached on the CDN. Correct? Could that work with a socket? (or a web socket?)

Comment: That's correct, it would be HTTP based and be the same as any other file.  The Web Socket route is completely different, and requires you to handle the infrastructure yourself.  Totally possible, but expensive.  You have to decide then whether to make it cheap and simple with increased latency, or lower latency for added complexity and price.

Comment: Cool, this answers my somewhat misdirected question. If you write this as an answer I'll accept it. Also, would be glad to learn more about the web-socket solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DASH and HLS streaming use normal file/blob-based HTTP CDNs.  The stream data is split into chunks/segments (usually ~4 seconds in duration) and uploaded, along with a manifest/playlist that tells the client what the URLs are for the chunks/segments.

Doing segmented streaming this way increases latency.  However, it does make it much more economical.  Rather than creating your own streaming infrastructure, you can use one of the many existing CDNs.  If you can handle a few seconds of latency, this is probably the right solution for you.

If latency matters more, you'll have the go the route of developing your own pub/sub system, or paying a lot to use an existing cloud solution.  These come with increased complexity.